# Shopware 6 Update/replace/overwrite pictures though API

Tags: image, api, replace, upload, shopware

There is a great guide how to upload pictures to Shopware 6.4:
[Add images via Shopware 6 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63618200/add-images-via-shopware-6-api/68902503#68902503)

But how do I update an image? I can get the media-id for the image, no problem, but if I use the _action route I will get an error the file already exists.

Comment: What the exact request? Are you using this one https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/adminapi.json/paths/~1_action~1media~1%7BmediaId%7D~1upload/post ?

Answer (score 2):

The [request documented here](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/adminapi.json/paths/%7E1_action%7E1media%7E1%7BmediaId%7D%7E1upload/post) should work.

If you are unsure with the API you can always do the according action in the admin panel (which uses the Shopware API itself).

In this cases you need to right-click on the image and choose the replace option. Then you can observer your browser's network tab (Ctrl+Shift+I) to look closer at the request the Shopware 6 admin panel is executing.

In my case this request looked like that:

```
/api/_action/media/add88aa462b44e4e93e06ef65a1542a8/upload?extension=pdf&fileName=dummy
Request Method: POST
```

Comment: Alex...thanks for the great tip watching what the browser is doing in admin.

And I found the error in my logic. I always tried to create a media ID first and of course I got an "file already exists" error, because the new media ID was not allowed to have the same filename as an existing ID.

Comment: When the `Media` with the `fileName` already exists, you need to use `PATCH` to the endpoint `/api/media`.